# Java - JSplitPane size of weight listener

Tags: java, swing, listener, jsplitpane

I have some problem with get value of resizing the weight of JSplitPane by mouse.

here my code :

```
splitpane.setResizeWeight(0.1);
splitpane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
                System.out.println (splitpane.getResizeWeight());
            }
        });
```

But it's always printed `0.1`.

and i have try using `JSplitPane.RESIZE_WEIGHT_PROPERTY`

```
splitpane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.RESIZE_WEIGHT_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
                System.out.println (splitpane.getResizeWeight());
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't not print anything.

Comment: What is the variable `hor`?

Comment: i'm sorry, i have edited.

Answer (score 3):

> But it's always printed 0.1.

Yes, because you set its value to 0.1. That property tells the split pane how to allocate space to the two components when the size of the split pane changes.

When you drag the divided with the mouse you are just changing the divider location. You are not affecting the resize property.

Maybe you are looking for the `getDividerLocation()` method?

Comment: i think i do not looking for it.
i just want looking for size of weight.

Comment: The resize property will only change if you manually set it. It is not used to give you the current ratio of size between the two components. If this is what you want then you can calculate the it yourself. The ratio of the two components is the divider location divided by the size of the scrollpane.

Comment: "The resize property will only change" ... strange that the listener still is triggered!